# Table Focus event is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, yui

I am using one event "tableFocusEvent" in YUI. It's working fine in FF but it's not working in IE.I tried to get similar event and use "focus" but that also not working.
Can anyone Please help me in this. Any help is appriciated.

My code is here

```
myDataTable.subscribe('tableFocusEvent', test);

function test()
{
 alert("Hii");
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: I'm looking at the [DataTable documentation for YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html#events) and there doesn't appear to be a focus event for DataTable's.

Comment: @Hatjhie, I am checking in IE8, but I also check checked in IE9 it was not working there also.

Comment: @Greg Actually I already got this code and need to debug and agreed with your comment but this is working in FF I also used focus event which is specified in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Kailash you can try this one I think this must be helpful.You have mentioned in your question that you have used focus event please check below code have you used like this way -

```
var items = Y.one('#items');

items.on('focus', function (e) {
    Y.log("testing for focus event");
});
```

Comment: It could be the bug from the YUI itself. Maybe you could combine it with JQuery. Something like: $(items).on("focus", function() {
  Y.log("testing for focus event");
});

JQuery and YUI can co-exist together.